# How to generate ids for tables made by php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a page to allow toggling on and off certain forums in website, created from raw data in an SQL server. However I need each to have an individual ID so I can show/hide them based on user preference. I am not sure how to go about it. Here is my existing code, disregard the connection values, I am hiding them on purpose. thanks.

```
$db_host = "host";
$db_username = "username";
$db_pass = "pass";
$db_name = "name";
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
$query = $db->query('SELECT p.name, p.company, o.prodtype AS Type
FROM ownedproducts AS o
JOIN product as p ON p.productID = o.productID
WHERE o.usersID = 2');
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<title> User Forum Selection </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
<input type="text" id="userid">
    </div>
    <div>
<hr>
<table id=table border = '2'>
<tr id=table-row>
<th id=table-header>Name</th>
<th id=table-header>Company</th>
<th id=table-header>Type</th>
</tr>
    
        
<?php
while ($row = $query->fetch()) 
{
    echo "<tr id=table-row >";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['company'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Type'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>

</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are quite a lot of elements missing from your HTML; there are syntax errors as well (e.g. `id` cannot be used more than once; attribute values should be wrapped with double quotes; no meta tag specified for encoding; no DOCTYPE, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the product id ? That sounds logical here.

Select it :

```sql
$query = $db->query('SELECT p.productID, p.name, p.company, o.prodtype AS Type ...
```

Then use it in your rows :

```php
while ($row = $query->fetch()) 
{
    
    echo "<tr id='table-row-" . $row['id'] . "' >";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['company'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Type'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: alternatively, `data-*` attribute can be used in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

> **Always use single and double quote in id as (id=' ', id=" ")**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<title> User Forum Selection </title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="userid">
  </div>
<div>
<hr>
  <table id=table border = '2'>
   <tr id=table-row>
     <th id=table-header>Name</th>
     <th id=table-header>Company</th>
     <th id=table-header>Type</th>
   </tr>

    
<?php
while ($row = $query->fetch()) 
{
  echo "<tr id=table-row >";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] ."</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['company'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Type'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
?>

</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

> **use it in your rows :**

```
<?php
foreach( $query->fetch() as $rows=> $row)
{
    echo "<tr id='table-row-'.$rows >";
    echo "<td>" . $row[or</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['company'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Type'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do it in a foreach and use the key.

```
foreach( $query->fetch() as $key => $row)
{
   echo "<tr id='table-row-'.$key >";
   echo "<td>" . $row['name'] ."</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['company'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['Type'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
}
```